# Why is "width=\textwidth" setting not properly scaling graphic?

Tags: graphics, margins, scaling, jpeg

I'm including a jpg figure in my LaTeX document like this:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]\centering
    % fbox here only for illustrative purposes
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{Pictures/PoolofBethesda-CarlBloch}}
%   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{Pictures/LesNocesdeCana-PaoloVeronese}
    \caption{\emph{Healing at the Pool of Bethesda} (1883) by Carl Bloch.}
    \label{fig:Bethesda}
\end{figure}
```

However, the picture is not being properly scaled. I want the picture to be as wide as the text on the page with the aspectratio kept the same. I get this instead; you can see the box where the image should be:

[image: Example of image not being scaled properly]

If I simply replace the image with a different image (as shown in the commented line above) everything works as expected.

**Why isn't my image being scaled properly? Am I missing something obvious?**

The original image is this:

[image: Original image]

PS. I'm using the `graphicx` package with no options.

Comment: Probably the graphic has some margins. Put \fbox around the image to see it. Or remove the keepaspectration key.

Comment: It might be useful for us to see that image, or as Ulrike suggests, wrap it in `\fbox{...}` in order to visually see where the edges of the image is. BTW: the `keepaspectratio` should not be necessary when you are only adding one scaling parameter. Should not do any harm either.

Comment: It is also possible that the graphic contains faulty resolution information (or that they are missing).

Comment: The second image works fine for me. But I doubt that it "the original image", tex.sx postprocesses images. You should put the image in a zip-file somewhere for download.

Comment: Try downloading from here:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/3bs5v3yyml0buzr/PoolofBethesda-CarlBloch.jpg

Comment: @Jeremy, see my comment, BTW: always provide a minimal example including the preamble etc. Some classes does strange things.

Comment: Works fine for me. Do you have other files with the name `PoolofBethesda-CarlBloch` in this folder? How are you compiling? Can you show the log-file?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer There is no other figure called `PoolofBethesda-CarlBloch`. You can download my log file from here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z9fz1q2qydq9oo7/Witnesses.log  It is for the complete compilation, not just the figure I showed.

Comment: Yes, xdvipdfmx of texlive 2014 has problems with the file, probably a problem with the resolution. It works fine in TL13 and miktex. You could convert the graphic to png to get around the problem.

Comment: Is the image metadata (i.e., resolution) wrong and that is what is causing problems in TeXLive 2014 or is it a problem with TL 2014?

Comment: Probably a combination. Something in the new version of xdvipdfmx gets confused by something unusual in the jpg. In TL13 your image works. Try a bug report (see xdvipdfmx --help for the address).

Answer (score 3):

Just for a larger comment. This works just fine for me

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% I do not have that path on my PC
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{PoolofBethesda-CarlBloch}
  \caption{\emph{Healing at the Pool of Bethesda} (1883) by Carl Bloch.}
  \label{fig:Bethesda}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```